# How to intercept a site http request using javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, events

I need to hook all links, images, css and js call URLs inside my site and execute some operation when an event occurs with then.

Anybody knows how to handle all these events?

Comment: Your question isn't vary clear, what type of "operation do you want to execute" and when do you want it to fire, after the objects are loaded into the DOM or when the request is made... 

_It's likely_ that your trying to do something outside the conventions of proper web development. Maybe ask your self, "why do I need to do this" in the first place, you may find it completely unnecessary.

Comment: you cant intercept site http by javascript, because javascript file itself is an http request, you need a web server and some sort of server side technology to do that

Comment: Hi,

I need handle HTTP requests because I want to observe and execute some action when some object perform that event. i.e., when img.src load some content from the server, I need to calculate the time spend for it.

Firebug and Yslow do that. But, I don't know how.

[]'s,

And Past

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$("link, script, style, a, img").each(function(){
    $(this).load(function(){
        // do stuff when each of these elements is loaded
    });
});
```

Not entirely sure if that is what you want, as your question isn't terribly clear, but that is how you can bind something to the load event for each of those element types.

Comment: `.each` is redundant here. You can just use `$("link, script, style, a, img").load`. Just a tip.

Comment: Yes!! We need that solution. That's the type of request that I qant handle!

Thanks,

And Past

Comment: But, I need some more complete artifact to achieve all HTTP requests. i.e., when jquery execute $.get('remoteFile.html',...) . How can I handle that request?
[]'s,

And Past

Answer (score 1):

If you need to catch everything with the same function you could use jQuery.  Something like this would attach a function to all links:

```
$('a').click(somefunction);
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery to re-use a function like this.

Comment: No you don't, but the selectors make it easy to make sure you get all the places you'd like to attach your function, while the load and click functions help handle cross browser issues smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers? `<body onload="somefunction"> <img src="blah.jpg" onLoad="somejavascriptfunction()" onclick="someotherfunction">`  and so on.

Can be done with most elements.